# I have two tables CREATE_TABLE_TEAM and CREATE_TABLE_PLAYER. How can I use primary key from TABLE_TEAM as a foreign key in TABLE_PLAYER?

Tags: java

I have two tables `CREATE_TABLE_TEAM` and `CREATE_TABLE_PLAYER`. How can I use primary key from `TABLE_TEAM` as a foreign key in `TABLE_PLAYER`?

```
private static final String  CREATE_TABLE_TEAM = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TEAM + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TEAM_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

private static final String  CREATE_TABLE_PLAYER = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLAYER + "(" + KEY_PLAYER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_PLAYER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
        KEY_ID + " INTEGER  FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES " + TABLE_TEAM + " (ID) )";
```

Comment: Can you please add SQL tag as well to the question? It will help you to get faster responses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for foreign key constraint:

```
private static final String  CREATE_TABLE_PLAYER = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PLAYER + "(" + KEY_PLAYER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_PLAYER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," +
    KEY_ID + " INTEGER  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES " + TABLE_TEAM + " (" + KEY_ID + " ) )";
```

`KEY_ID` from `TABLE_TEAM` is set as a foreign key in `TABLE_PLAYER`

Comment: private static final String CREATE_TABLE_PLAYER = "create table "
            + TABLE_PLAYER + " ("
            + KEY_PLAYER_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + KEY_PLAYER_NAME + " text not null,"
            + KEY_TEAM_ID + " integer,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_TEAM_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_TEAM+"("+KEY_TEAM_ID+"));";